# Addressing of instruction pointer in Mac OS X x86-64

Tags: c, macos, assembly, osx-mountain-lion

I wanted to understand a litte more about assembly and wrote a little example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void f() {
  unsigned char i[4];
  i[0] = 5;
  i[1] = 6;
  i[2] = 7;
  i[3] = 8;
  int j = 0;
  for(j=0; j < 20; j++)
    printf("%02X\n", i[j]);

}

int main() {
  int i[5];
  i[0] = 3;
  i[1] = 3;
  i[2] = 3;
  i[3] = 3;
  i[4] = 3;
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

My goal was to see the actual return address for the instruction pointer, laid down by the call to
callq in main(), when it started f().

I used gdb to disassemble main() and got the following

```
 Dump of assembler code for function main:
 0x0000000100000eb0 <main+0>:   push   %rbp
 0x0000000100000eb1 <main+1>:   mov    %rsp,%rbp
 0x0000000100000eb4 <main+4>:   sub    $0x20,%rsp
 0x0000000100000eb8 <main+8>:   movl   $0x3,-0x1c(%rbp)
 0x0000000100000ebf <main+15>:  movl   $0x3,-0x18(%rbp)
 0x0000000100000ec6 <main+22>:  movl   $0x3,-0x14(%rbp)
 0x0000000100000ecd <main+29>:  movl   $0x3,-0x10(%rbp)
 0x0000000100000ed4 <main+36>:  movl   $0x3,-0xc(%rbp)
 0x0000000100000edb <main+43>:  callq  0x100000e40 <f>
 0x0000000100000ee0 <main+48>:  movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
 0x0000000100000ee7 <main+55>:  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
 0x0000000100000eea <main+58>:  mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
 0x0000000100000eed <main+61>:  mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
 0x0000000100000ef0 <main+64>:  add    $0x20,%rsp
 0x0000000100000ef4 <main+68>:  pop    %rbp
 0x0000000100000ef5 <main+69>:  retq
```

so i was expecting to find the laid down instruction pointer return address to be 0x0000000100000ee0, as this is the next instruction after callq. When I run my program I get ( I grouped these in groups of 4 so you can read them better):

```
05
06
07
08

40
1B
08
56

FF
7F
00
00

E0
EE
B7
09

01
00
00
00

00
00
00
00

03
00
00
00

03
00
00
00

03
00
00
00

03
00
00
00
```

Ok, so I can see my 5,6,7,8 that I wrote into my local variable in f() and I can see the local variables of main() those 4-byte integers, which have been set to 3. After 5,6,7,8 (this is a 64 bit system) I would have expected the next 8 bytes to encode the previous value of the %rbp register, and THEN the
next 8 bytes to contain the return address for the instruction pointer. So the return address should be

```
E0
EE
B7
09

01
00
00
00
```

Now when I compare this to the 0x0000000100000ee0 that I am expecting from gdb, I can see the 00000001 in the last 4 bytes and I can see the e0 from 00000ee0 in the very first byte. But why am I not getting exactly what I am expecting? I thought about byte-ordering (Mac OS X is little endian I believe), but that would not explain what I see here, from what I understood.

Any input is welcome,

Thank you guys,

Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this program and run it multiple times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int foo;

    printf("%p %p\n", main, &foo);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that you'll get different addresses every time. MacOS has position independent binaries and the stack changes positions all the time too. This is a security feature.

If you run your program in gdb, you'll probably get what you expect since gdb disables the randomization to make debugging easier.